# Is there a way to query how many blocks a critical section has?

Tags: delphi

I have a multi-threaded Delphi application which utilizes **TCriticalSection**.   Periodically the thread count starts to get very high.  Eventually, after about 30 seconds, all threads process.  I suspect maybe the code encapsulated within my Critical Section is sometimes taking longer than usual to process.  And therefore putting "blocks" on all other threads.

Is there a way to query CritialSections and find out how many threads they are currently blocking?

```
try
  ReportCriticalSection.Acquire;
  ........
finally
  ReportCriticalSection.Release;
end;
```

Comment: The code in the question is wrong. The try is in the wrong place. Put it immediately after the resource is acquired.

Comment: You could always just pause the debugger and look at your threads' call stacks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `TRtlCriticalSection.LockCount` field. In `TCriticalSection`, the RTL structure is a protected field.

Matt Pietrek and Russ Osterlund published an article in *MSDN Magazine* several years ago that includes descriptions of what all the fields mean. Use them for debugging only, not business logic.

[Break Free of Code Deadlocks in Critical Sections Under Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the counts.  This help me solve a major problem in my service.  Question: what is the purpose of having LockCount be protected?  Why not just make it public so that people can get access to it without deriving from TCriticalSection?

Comment: It's not that LockCount is protected; the entire TRtlCriticalSection record is protected. It's an implementation detail of the Windows version of TCriticalSection. Heck, even LockCount itself is generally an implementation detail; I don't think MSDN documents it.